# Can not catch errors in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm using codeigniter4.1.4 as api server and using postman to test.
If error occurrence in backend, it make log file in logs directory on the server but not return error. So I must check log files at each time. How to catch error in http response?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Config\Exceptions file set $log variable from true to false.